# How to use column with linkToItem in the Basic Table view style mode

Tags: list, column, view

I have already changed a normal column that I made to a column with `linkToItem` as follows.

```
<viewfields>
<FieldRef Name="MyColumn" linkToItem="TRUE">
```

and it worked.

But this column works only at the default view style mode.

Does anyone know how to use linkedToItem column in the Basic Table mode?

Answer (score 1):

In MS tech forum, other user taught me the solution.
so I'll share it in here too.

*in the Default style view, we need to use linkToItem=”TRUE”. However,
in Basic Table style view, we need to use LinkToItem=”TRUE” instead.*